# Match in Nginx location returns an empty $1 although redirect works

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm new to Nginx and I need to permanently redirect an URL like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.ext/mars/2015/mypage.php?foo=1&bar=0
```

to another one like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.ext/earth?year=2015&foo=1&bar=0
```

The location directive I tried to use (within server{ ... }) is the following:

```
location ~ ^/mars/([0-9]+)/mypage.php {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/earth?year=$1&$args;
}
```

Everything works but $1 which is empty, i.e.  in the above example the URL actually yelded by the redirect is:

```
https://www.mywebsite.ext/earth?year=&foo=1&bar=0
```

(the value of 'year' should be "2015" instead)

What did I do wrong? How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: You could use a named capture group instead: `(?<year>[0-9]+)`, and then use `$year` var.

Comment: @wp78de Wow, you answered my question. The redirect works exactly as expected using the named capture group. Thank you very much! If you copy the comment above as an answer I'll be glad to credit it as the Best Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above, you could use a named capture group instead: `(?<year>[0-9]+)` and then use the `$year` var in the redirect.

```
location ~ ^/mars/(?<year>[0-9]+)/mypage.php {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/earth?year=$year&$args;
}
```